# XHTML to PDF using Flying Saucer and iText issue

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, flying-saucer

I was able to convert XHTML to pdf using Flying Saucer and iText. However of the XHTML has an anchor tag, I am not getting it as link in the pdf. How do i render the link as it is in the pdf also.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i am using `ITextRenderer()` and links are converted to links which also work in pdfs automatically.

show us some code

Answer (score 0):

In iText, create a [Chunk](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/Chunk.html) with the text representing the link and call its [setAnchor](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/Chunk.html#setAnchor%28java.lang.String%29) to link it some URL.

Comment: That's not an option via Flying Saucer.